# Using React, how do I add a component before removing it from the DOM after a certain time?

Tags: javascript, reactjs

After an event occurs, I would like to prepend a DOM element to a specified location and display a specified message, and then after a specified amount of time, I want it to be removed from the DOM. How can I achieve this using React? I am currently doing it with jQuery but would like to rewrite this functionality in React.

```
function prependMessage(prependToElementSelector, message, timeout) {
  $(prependToElement).prepend('<div id="search-confirmation-message"><p>' + message + '</p></div>');

  setTimeout(function() {
    $('#search-confirmation-message').remove()
  }, timeout);
}

// Run this method whenever an event occurs
prependMessage('#search-panel-container', 'Your filters have been updated.', 2500);
```

Comment: You can use `ref`s to achieve the same thing.  Not a huge win imho, but it's pure React.  Also https://www.npmjs.com/package/react-alert or the like might appeal to you.

Comment: you don't need to remove anything manually, just make sure the template works and setState() using a timer.

Comment: Interesting. Can you please provide code samples?

Answer (score 2):

You can create a component which displays the message and unloads itself after a certain period elapses.

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';

class TimedMessage extends Component {
    constructor(props) {
        super(props);
        this.state ={show:true}

    }
    componentDidMount() {
        setTimeout(this.setState({show:false}, this.props.timeout));
    }

    render() {
        let element =this.state.show?<div id="search-confirmation-message"><p>' +{this.props.message} + '</p></div>:null;
        return element;
    }
}

export default TimedMessage;
```

Whichever component handles the event should be able to display this component on the occurrence of the event, using an event handler which sets a flag in the state

```
onSomethingHappened= ()=>{
this.setState({showMessage:true})}
```

and checking the flag and rendering the component in the render method

```
render(){
...

    return(
    ...

    {this.state.showMessage?<TimedMessage message={"This is my timed message"} timeout={5000} />:null}

    ...
    );

}
```

**Edit after comments:**
Component code :

```
import React, { Component } from "react";

class TimedMessage extends Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.state = { show: true };
  }
  startTimer=()=>{
    this.setState({ show: true });
    setTimeout(() => this.setState({ show: false }), this.props.timeout);
  }
  componentDidMount() {

    this.startTimer();
  }
  componentWillReceiveProps() { this.startTimer();}
  render() {
    let element = this.state.show ? (
      <div>
        <p>{this.props.message} </p>
      </div>
    ) : null;

    return element;
  }
}

export default TimedMessage;
```

Sandbox : https://codesandbox.io/s/1474451lk4

Comment: This is an interesting idea, but it will only render the message once. If I try to run the event again to show the message, it won't show again, because `this.props.show` inside `<TimedMessage>` never resets back to `true`. :(

Comment: You can do that by resetting the state everytime your component mounts. So you can add a line `this.setState({show:true});`  in `componentDidMount`  before the `setTimeout` call.

Comment: You mean AFTER the setTimeout call?

Comment: Your suggestion doesn't work, since the `this.setState({ show: false })` in `setTimeout()` will just override it. And the main issue is actually that the `state.showMessage`in the parent component actually needs to be reset, but in order to do that, the setTimeout() would need to be on the parent component, which makes the `<TimedMessage>` component no longer necessary and not modular.

Comment: My bad! The code should use `componentWillReceiveProps` not `componentDidMount`. I have edited my code accordingly.